# Model validation in Web API - Exception is thrown with out a throw statement?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have seen the `model validation` from [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api) (Under section: `Handling Validation Errors`).

The code-snippet is as below in `Web API`

```
public class ValidateModel : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            if (actionContext.ModelState.IsValid == false)
            {
                actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(
                    HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, actionContext.ModelState);
            }

            base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
        }
    }
```

The problem is `upon validation of model`, if there were any errors, `it assigns an model state invalid` exception.

And after that, before going to the actual method (which is decorated with this `[ValidateModel]` attribute), WebAPI simply returns a 400 request.

But how ? Which function is returning a `HTTP 400`?

What happens after this method is done executing? Where does the control flow ?

**EDIT:**

The action that I am applying this attribute to is a normal one.

```
[ValidateModel]
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]Request)
{
//do normal business logics here.
return Ok(SuccessMessage);
}
```

Comment: Could have something to do with the method called `CreateErrorResponse`. Sounds like that might create an error response

Comment: 1) use try..catch , and catch the error , as Daveparsons said , it may be CreateErrorResponse function. 2) Is there is a filter that is fired befor this ?

Comment: @Zakos: No, it does not throw any error at all.. I removed `actionContext.Response` so that the `CreateErrorResponse` will be called. But it is returning a `200`

Comment: @DaveParsons: `try` `catch` does not catch the exceptions.. The control simply flows down.

Comment: @Zakos: Also, there are no filters used before this.

Comment: wait ,r u asking why it throw 400 on invalid model ? that's the WebApi design...Bad Reqeust = 400 ,  actionContext.Response is the "answer"

Comment: @Zakos: No, I am asking `how does it throw a 400`. We see that there is **no throw statement** or **no return 400 statement at all** in the above code.

Comment: This is how Web Api works . This is the design & architecture of Web Api.
When you set a value to actionContext.Response  , in this example you set it to BadRequest , which is 400, this is answer of the server.
200 is OK answer by the server.
And when actionContext.Response  is set , it doesn't move forward to the Controller, the request is done! 
Now , when you say "Throw" , we automatically thing about an error , exception , which is not this case. So please pay attention. There is no error / expcetion here. Your code says : if the model is invalid - answer 400 , otherwise continue.

Comment: If you actually mean `it throws an model state invalid exception` can you please share its stack trace?

Comment: @Ramesh: Sorry, It does not throw exceptions. This method is executed and after that `before the control flows to the actual method (to which this action filter is applied), the webapi returns a BadRequest (400))

Comment: Can you show the action you apply the ValidateModel attribute to? Side note: The attribute class name should e suffixed with the Attribute.

Comment: @Tibi: I wonder thats not necessary and in `WebAPI` you need not suffix it. It just works fine.

Comment: @Tibi: I have updated the question to show the action .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To understand the control flow you first need to visit this link here -

[Action Attribute Class Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Check the method sections there. If clearly states that, `OnActionExecuting` is performed before that particular action, decorated with this attribute, is executed and `OnActionExecuted` is performed after the execution is complete. Since you are implementing `OnActionExecuting` like this -

```
public class ValidateModel : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext.ModelState.IsValid == false)
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(
                HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, actionContext.ModelState);
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
    }
}
```

and since the error is thrown inside this method, like this  -

```
 if (actionContext.ModelState.IsValid == false)
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(
                HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, actionContext.ModelState);
        }
```

Your method will only execute if the `OnActionExecuting` method finds a valid model. And from the error 400, it seems that your current model state is not valid and thus it fails to succeed and your method will never be executed unless you provide a valid model. Set a debug point inside this method and you can find out why it fails.

By the way, the exception is not thrown its just a standard response that is handled by -

```
base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
```

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute(v=vs.118).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

To find the error point just create a break point on Application_Error in Global.asax and follow the error details and stack trace to find the origin for the same.

Answer (score 1):

When method OnActionExecuting is called it checks to see if the Model is valid. If Model is not valid 
actionContext.Response will be calling server which will return 400 code back meaning the it was bad request. 
It all depends how you are calling this web api. Normally you can have jquery or some other libraries or code behind from asp.net making the call to the webapi's with appropriate object. That object is first checked if it is valid or not. If it is valid it will keep processing nothing is returned back. If object state is invalid than it will return the status code 400. If it is returning 200 than it means your object is valid and web api executed and is returning 200. This 200 is not being returned from webapi but from EF after data was written sucessfully.
If you want to use try catch block than you dont need to check if model is valid. Just pass through the url with object and wait for response than catch it and display.

Answer (score 1):

If your `Request` data type is defined as `struct`, or an `abstract class`, it cannot be instantiated, and that might be the probable cause. If is a struct, just make it `Nullable`, if it is an abstract class or `interface` you can either create your own `ModelBinder` to deal with the creation, or you can change it with a concrete implementation.

Comment: Thanks. But, I am not discussing here about the `model class`. All I wanted to know is `what happens after you assign a bad request response to actionContext.Response`. How an error is thrown ? (Please see the `ValidateModel` attribute code_

Comment: Is this you are looking for? http://www.asp.net/posters/web-api/asp.net-web-api-poster-grayscale.pdf

Answer (score 0):

In VBA.NET API REST
Validate model

```
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

Public Class Client
    <Required(ErrorMessage:="Dpi is required")>
    Public Property Dpi As String

    <MaxLength(16, ErrorMessage:="El NAME no debe ser mayor a 16 caracteres.")>
    Public Property NAME As String
End Class
```

CONTROLLER

```
    <Route("UPDATE/client")>
    <ActionName("description to do...")>
    <HttpPost>
    Public Function saveClient(ByVal cli As Client)


        If ModelState.IsValid Then
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, True)
        Else
            Return BadRequest(ModelState)
        End If
 End Function
```