# How to make "One or more validation errors occurred" raise an exception?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm running a WebAPI on Core 3.1 and one of my endpoints excepts JSON with a model that has fields with `[Required]` attribute like so:

```
public class Vendor
{
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "UID is required")]   <<<------ required attribute
        public string UID { get; set; }
}
```

When i call this endpoint without setting UID I get the following output as expected:

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "|7ced8b82-4aa34d65daa99a12.",
    "errors": {
        "Vendor.UID": [
            "UID is required"
        ]
    }
}
```

Altho this output is pretty informative and clear it is not consistent with other error outputs that my API produces by means of ExceptionFilter. Is there any way this errors can be routed to the exception filter as well?

Here is my Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            Common.Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);
            services.AddMvc().AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters();
            services.AddMvc().AddMvcOptions(options =>
            {
                options.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
            });
            services.AddMvcCore(options => options.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerOutputFormatter()));
            services.AddOptions();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILogger<Startup> logger)
        {

            //Middleware for exception filtering
            app.UseMiddleware<ErrorHandlingMiddleware>(new ErrorHandlingMiddlewareOptions { logger = logger });

            app.UseStaticFiles();            

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute("EndpointNotFound", "{*url}", new { controller = "Error", action = "EndpointNotFound" });
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

You can add filter in your mvc service or controller service

this filter return badrequest

```
services.AddControllers(option =>
{
             option.Filters.Add<ValidationFilter>();
});
```

to create your filter you can add this class
also you can customize this filter to what ever you want

```
public class ValidationFilter : IAsyncActionFilter
    {
        public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
        {
            //before contrller

            if(!context.ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var errorsInModelState = context.ModelState
                    .Where(x => x.Value.Errors.Count > 0)
                    .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value.Errors.Select(x => x.ErrorMessage).ToArray());

                var errorResponse = new ErrorResponse();

                foreach (var error in errorsInModelState)
                {
                    foreach (var subError in error.Value)
                    {
                        var errorModel = new ErrorModel
                        {
                            FieldName = error.Key,
                            Message = subError
                        };

                        errorResponse.Error.Add(errorModel);
                    }

                    context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(errorResponse);
                    return;
                }

                await next();

                //after controller  
            }
        }
    }
```

I have created error model just like this

```
public class ErrorModel
    {
        public string FieldName { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
```

and error response like below

```
public class ErrorResponse
    {
        public List<ErrorModel> Error { get; set; } = new List<ErrorModel>();
        public bool Successful { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I implemented everything exacly as you layed out, but still getting 400 generic error :(

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at the great library [FluentValidation](https://fluentvalidation.net/)!

Sample:

Build a validator module binding your DTO and create a set of rules.

```cs
public class CustomerValidator : AbstractValidator<Customer> {
  public CustomerValidator() {
    RuleFor(x => x.Surname).NotEmpty();
    RuleFor(x => x.Forename).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Please specify a first name");
    RuleFor(x => x.Discount).NotEqual(0).When(x => x.HasDiscount);
    RuleFor(x => x.Address).Length(20, 250);
    RuleFor(x => x.Postcode).Must(BeAValidPostcode).WithMessage("Please specify a valid postcode");
  }

  private bool BeAValidPostcode(string postcode) {
    // custom postcode validating logic goes here
  }
}
```

Inject it in your controllers through DI:

```cs
    services.AddControllers()
                .AddFluentValidation(s =>
                {
                    s.ValidatorOptions.CascadeMode = CascadeMode.Stop;
                    s.RunDefaultMvcValidationAfterFluentValidationExecutes = false;
                    s.ValidatorOptions.LanguageManager.Culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
                    s.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Customer>();
                    
                    ...
                    // more validators
                });
```

- That way your code looks well organized;
- You get rid of Data Annotations spread all over your code.
- Personalize error messages and validations.

You also may want to check why implementing [ControllerBase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-5.0) on your controllers might be the way to go while using web APIs.

Answer (score 1):

In order to achive this functionality you need to implement your own model validator described in this question: [Model validation in Web API - Exception is thrown with out a throw statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24159615/model-validation-in-web-api-exception-is-thrown-with-out-a-throw-statement)

Comment: I want thru the answers and microsoft articles on how to setup an attribute filter but still cannot make it run mu custom login in "OnActionExecuting"... can you please provide a short code snippet with key components of startup.cs and other related items? Thanks!

Comment: If you are using [ApiController] by default the apibehavior automatically return HTTP 400. You can suppress this (meaning you'll have to check model state by yourself - I would not personally suggest that given it can be error prone) or customize the error output via ```InvalidModelStateResponseFactory```. Here is an [official example](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/2e4274cb67c049055e321c18cc9e64562da52dcf/src/Mvc/test/WebSites/BasicWebSite/StartupWithCustomInvalidModelStateFactory.cs) for the latter.

I would not suggest creating custom action filter just for this.

Comment: btw if you still want to go with the action filter route (checking ```ModelState.IsValid``` manually by yourself), check the [filter scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-3.1#filter-scopes-and-order-of-execution) from the official doc.

Answer (score 1):

I have just change in http methos and work fine for the same issue

```
[HttpPost("authenticate")]
public IActionResult Authenticate([FromBody]AuthenticateModel model)
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to output the JSON like this:

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "|7ced8b82-4aa34d65daa99a12.",
    "errors": {
        "Vendor.UID": [
            "UID is required"
        ]
    }
}
```

1. the `type` and the `status` field, are from here https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/v3.1.17/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/DependencyInjection/ApiBehaviorOptionsSetup.cs#L54-L108, the `ClientErrorMapping` will be configured when the dotnet core project setup.
2. the JSON was a `ValidationProblemDetails` which created by the `DefaultProblemDetailsFactory`, https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/v3.1.17/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Infrastructure/DefaultProblemDetailsFactory.cs#L45
3. we can use this `ProblemDetailsFactory` to create the ValidationProblemDetails https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/v3.1.17/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/DependencyInjection/MvcCoreServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L261