# Enum string parameter handling in REST API in C#

Tags: c#, rest, enums

I have to write a service which gets enum string as parameter in POST service. For simplicity let it be json body containing Name and Sex. Name is a string and Sex can be either "MALE" or "FEMALE". Of course I can handle this as plain strings. However I predict that we will have more services with enums so it would be beneficial to find a standard way of passing them. Also Swagger specification is better when using string enum because all acceptable values are in the service specification.

I've found a way how to to that but it was harder and more complicated than I've thought initially so I would like to check if somebody have something simpler.
I've learned that it can be done this way:

```
public class PersonDto
{
    /// <example>John</example>
    public string Name { get; set; }
    /// <example>MALE</example>
    public SexType Sex { get; set; }
}

[System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
public enum SexType
{
    MALE, FEMALE
}
```

Basically this works. Then I've tested what happen when incorrect value is entered.
First surprise: my controller code is not executed (it can be expected) but also centralized error handling middleware is also not executed. This is because there is no exception raised so the middleware has nothing to intercept.

Effect: error is not logged and response is in non-standard format. I would rather expect behavior similar to that when int field is filled with non-numeric string.
Fortunately I've found solution here: [How to make "One or more validation errors occurred" raise an exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62771426/229860).
Then next problem: what if I pass value 666?
It appears that all integer values are treated as correct!

So I've looked at the definition of JsonStringEnumConverter. I can't inherit from it because CreateConverter is sealed. So I've wrote my own class similar to JsonStringEnumConverter. The only difference was CreateConverter method - I've just created new instance of JsonStringEnumConverter passing argument allowIntegerValues: false to constructor.

```
public class CustomJsonStringEnumConverter : JsonConverterFactory
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public sealed override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert)
    {
        return typeToConvert.IsEnum;
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public sealed override JsonConverter CreateConverter(Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (typeToConvert.IsEnum)
        {
            JsonStringEnumConverter jsonStringEnumConverter = new(allowIntegerValues: false);

            return jsonStringEnumConverter;
        }

        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

This fails on start with message 'SexType.CustomJsonStringEnumConverter' cannot return an instance of JsonConverterFactory. I do not know why - everything is similar to JsonStringEnumConverter.

Next I've tried custom attribute:

```
public class JsonStringEnumAttribute : JsonConverterAttribute
{
    public JsonStringEnumAttribute() : base(null)
    {
    }

    public override JsonConverter? CreateConverter(Type x)
    {
        return JsonStringEnumConverter(allowIntegerValues: false);
    }
}
```

It works exactly as JsonStringEnumConverter: it allows all numeric values. Once again I don't understand why.
Finally I've got working solution from ChatGpt:

```
public class StringEnumConverter<TEnum> : JsonConverter<TEnum> where TEnum : struct, Enum
{
    public override TEnum Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.String)
        {
            string enumString = reader.GetString();
            if (Enum.TryParse<TEnum>(enumString, true, out TEnum enumValue))
                if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(TEnum), enumValue))
                    return enumValue;
        }

        throw new JsonException($"Invalid enum value '{reader.GetString()}'");
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TEnum value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString());
    }
}

[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter<SexType>))]
public enum SexType
{
    MALE, FEMALE
}
```

However I think that simpler solution should exist because base implementation is already done as JsonStringEnumConverter class and the only missing piece is to pass allowIntegerValues to the constructor.
Is it possible to handle string enums correctly without implementing Read/Write methods of JsonConverter?

Comment: _"Is it possible to handle string enums correctly without implementing Read/Write methods of JsonConverter?"_ you can have a string property and parse and validate it manually. But the most convenient way is probably the way you did it.